# What type of cable to use for a low voltage heating element?

Tags: electrical, wiring, conduit

I have a 960W transformer, the output measured 26V.

This is supplying power for an underfloor heating element which simply draws less current with lower voltage so maybe the actual power is say 750W, that is ~29A.

With 2.5mm cable, 20m away at the elements I measure 17.5V, but at the transformer, it is 26V, so apparently cable needs to be much thicker and the cable is even heating up the conduit, I don't like that!

I could mount the transformer closer but for noise, practicality and aesthetics I'm first considering ways around it.

So I'm thinking of upgrading to a 4mm twin or up to 6mm twin and earth. I wish there were an alternative wire to use (without earth) but I couldn't find a thick solid pair cable without earth. But I can easily remove earth from T&E if I also remove the grey sheath which would also work because in the existing conduit, there's already too many wires and I won't fit another unless I get rid of unneeded material.

Or I could use a flexible cable but aren't these a lot thicker than solid core? I dont need flexibility so I haven't considered this as an option but maybe?

The conduit is a plastic square-profile with a snap-in plastic covering. I just easily put cable in and snap cover back into place.

Comment: Flexible cable isn't necessarily thicker. In fact, stranded wire typically has a _higher_ current rating than solid, meaning you may be able to use a smaller gauge.

Comment: I have actually tried both 2.5mm flexible and 2.5mm solid as I suggested (I didnt realize the original flexible one was also 2.5mm, my mistake). But both heating up similarly, or maybe the solid one even more a little? I dont have a thermal camera. But The solid takes slightly less space.

Comment: A quick search indicates that 2.5mm wire is rated at ~15 Amps (slightly more in conduit). You're playing with fire there. Literally.

Comment: Ah is that the rating from https://www.lightwiring.co.uk/lighting-circuit-components/light-cables/twin-and-earth-cable-current-ratings/ I saw it the first time and looked at the wrong column

Comment: I read it as the B option when "enclosed in conduit or trunking on or in a wall.", that would be 23A

Comment: I know in the US you will not find solid wire over 10awg  but stranded no limit ok 750kcmil /mcm depending on how old you are is massive.  So in reality for perimeter or house wiring there are only 3 sizes of copper wire 14, 12, 10 awg.  I did not do the math but if it 29A the wire would need to be 8awg to be properly sized.

Comment: I don't know what the conduit fill rules are in your country, but it sounds very much like you've already hit or possibly exceeded them with the 2.5mm wire you have. When you increase the wire size to properly carry the current to this heater, it sounds like you'll easily exceed the fill limits. I would suggest you further investigate this and plan on running a new conduit just for these wires. It will help keep you within code compliance and, more importantly, help prevent an electrical fire that could take down your entire house.

Comment: Additionally, in the US, you're not allowed to remove the individual wires from a cable and run them in conduit. The wires aren't properly labeled, and often, they're not properly insulated to be used without the outer sheath. This would be another thing for you to investigate before you plan to strip that sheath off of a cable. However, based on [Harper's calculations](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/247985/34147), you'll probably be purchasing individual wires, not a cable anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I'm based in UK, should've mentioned.

Comment: In light of your comment I decided to RE-number-crunch based on your voltage measurements which I trust, though I did rely on your claim of wire length.  This indicates a much more serious problem, or to use the Canadian term, a "gong show".  You need to collect more data and then make a decision.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Voltage drop" calculations are a solved problem and there are web sites which will do it for you.

However, we see a lot of people not bother to do those calculations as they blunder into low-voltage high-current projects.  I've seen two major Youtube homesteaders have off-grid power projects **completely fail, because of this alone**.

Their blunder was they guessed at the wire size increase *but did not do the calculation*, possibly because they were afraid of the answer they would get. Worse for them: the wire they did buy (10 AWG copper, or 4 mm<sup>2</sup>) was about the same price as the wire they *needed* (2 AWG *aluminum* or 34 mm<sup>2</sup>).

### Can we figure the heater's actual ampacity?

We can most likely model this heater like a resistor.  You have *voltage* measurements but did not use a clamp meter to get current.  But we can figure it because we know the resistance of the 20m (each way) 2.5mm<sup>2</sup> wire.

2.5 is .0069 ohms per meter.
40 meters is thus 0.276 ohms.
So here is what we have.

[image]

We know from the differential voltage readings how much *voltage drop* is happening in the wires. Note the top center area of the diagram, we can plug that into Ohm's Law:

```
  Voltage = Current x Resistance
  8.5V drop = Current x 0.276 ohms
  30.79 amps = Current *right now as miswired*
```

Since it's a loop, current is exactly the same in all parts of it. So now we can solve for the heater's resistance. *Mind you this resistance value is only valid when the heater is operational. Shut off the resistance will be different. Heaters are not always linear.

```
 Voltage = Current x Resistance
 17.5V = 30.79A x Resistance
 0.568 ohms = Resistance of heater
```

Well, now we're getting somewhere.  Now we can see how much current the heater will draw when we fix the wiring defects and deliver the full 26 volts to it.

```
 Voltage = Current x Resistance
 26V = Current x 0.568 ohms of heater
 45.8A = Current of heater on 26V
```

***Holy smokes.  That is NOT what you thought.*** Let that sink in for a minute.

```
 26V x 45.8A = 1191 watts of heater heat.
```

So the transformer is not adequate, either.

This is a total gong show.  I have a feeling that the "professional" installers who wired this *were well aware of this*, and intentionally used the dangerously-small wire as a resistor to avoid burn-up of the transformer.

It certainly explains why they carried 26 volts for 20 meters instead of putting the transformer closer to the heater.

SMH wow... just wow.

Is this heater even designed for 26 volts? Time to look closer at its specs and nameplate.

**Using the running wire as a resistor like that is illegal.** Because it involves running the wire far beyond safe limits.  If I'm reading European wire specs correctly, you need 16mm<sup>2</sup> wire for 46A.

Wow, yeah. That's crazy.

### Any way you slice it, you need a new transformer.

If you plan to supply full 26 volts to the heater (can it take that?) you will get over twice the heat you are getting now.  However you will need a larger transformer capable of the 1191 watts.

Right now at 17.5 volts (31A) you are getting 542 watts of heat. If that is the right amount for you, you could use a smaller supply transformer such as 18 volts (573 watts).  So you have a bit of a "knob you can turn" (though, respect the heater nameplate rating).

Note that if you are able to down-jumper your existing transformer, doing so affects its power rating! Read the documentation carefully.

As far as the wires, the Code minimum wire (is it 16mm<sup>2</sup>?) is the bare minimum to be not unsafe.  It still will have considerable *voltage drop*. You may need to enlarge wires further to bring voltage drop within sensible limits. Let's "crunch the numbers" on voltage drop.

- 26 volts
- 46 amps
- 20 metres
- Target of 6% voltage drop  (1.5 volts drop)

I'm just hopping on the bog-standard North American calculator, and entering that stuff.  I get [3 AWG copper](https://www.wireandcableyourway.com/3-awg-thhn-building-wire) (27 mm<sup>2</sup>) and I believe you have 25 and 35 mm<sup>2</sup> as standard sizes.

... but we would never use copper for that in North America, we'd use [1 AWG aluminum](https://www.wireandcableyourway.com/1-awg-xhhw-2-aluminum-building-wire) (42 mm<sup>2</sup>). (the limiting factor is the cost of connectors to step down to smaller copper wire, if the device has copper-only lugs.) Unfortunately aluminum is not readily available in the 230V world.

### Fire the fool

**So how was this wired with a wire 4 times smaller? Get rid of whoever made such a basic safety blunder... they are unqualified for this work**.  You seem like the kind of person who *could acquire* the competence to work safely with electrical; you may have to do that if you can't find competent help.

Note that people who install heaters are not necessarily licensed electricians, and may not make good electrical decisions.  However if your country has a "permits and inspections" process, this would have been caught.

Comment: It doesnt actually draw 960W, that's only the transformer rating. I was told that the system will draw 750W.

Comment: @Daniel No, in the question you **guessed** it was drawing 750W and thought that was ***because** the voltage was degraded*, a very reasonable assumption, I thought.  So we don't really know what the heater is drawing.  If only we had a shunt resistor of known value --- *oh wait, we do*.  The resistance per length of 2.5mm wire is known.  Let me crunch some numbers.

Comment: Nonetheless actually, I give you that, I had originally wanted to exclude their transformer from the kit and buy my own toroidal transformer separately of exactly 1200W (I was guessing a safe margin), but I just couldn't find any, so I just went with this default one which they provided me. (I did this once before so I knew exactly what I was going into)

Comment: @DanielKatz In that case, the one takeaway is that the choice of 2.5mm cable was competely incompetent. Obviously they just grabbed it because it's a common size. It should have been *at least* 10 or 16mm as a safety requirement, based on your local codes.  That will limit wire heat to a safe level.  Then, you can use larger wire still to save money on electric costs (heating the heater not the wires to it).